# How to get the stored procedure's parameter from an input box

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Here i have called the stored procedure which works fine but i want to give the parameter in an input box how to get that from the input box

```
<?php 
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=acc_project_inv",'root','');

$sql = "CALL calcPro('2018-03-31')";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result->execute();
if ($result) {
            echo "Calculated";
        }else{
            echo "Report Development Team";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="yymmdd">
            <input type="submit" value="Do it!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=acc_project_inv",'root','');

if (!empty($_POST["yymmdd"])) {
  $ymd = $_POST["yymmdd"];

  // You should add more checks here to make sure that the $ymd
  // variable only contains expected characters (since it's user
  // input)

  $sql = "CALL calcPro( :yyyymmdd )";
  $result = $con->prepare($sql);
  $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $result->execute([":yyyymmdd" => $ymd]);
  if ($result) {
    echo "Calculated";
  } else {
    echo "Report Development Team";
  }
}
```

Comment: I want get it from an input box

Comment: unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\accounts\dont\callsp.php on line 13

Comment: @MONEYMSN I'm sorry. The only line I didn't test locally contained a syntax error. Updated.

Comment: @ jonasdev Thanq so much man. You are really great  in helping people's

Comment: Hello @ jonasdev

Comment: Hello @moneymsn

Comment: can you give me code for date filtering and search and filter the data tables and then export to excel?? @  jonasdev